# How do I access Gmail in lynx?

Tags: gmail, https, lynx

Client does not support https. That is all I am getting. I even tried the basic HTML link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works for me:

http://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=html

or

http://mail.google.com/a/YOURDOMAIN/?ui=html

Ctrl-X E to edit in external editor.

---

Are you using a version prior to 2.8.7?

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=488219

---

**EDIT**:
I downloaded the oldest of the 2.8.8 lynx sources. After trying out different options it was configured without ssl support by default and I reproduced the error. Configuring & building lynx in the following way fixed the problem:

```
# download the lynx source
./configure --with-ssl --enable-gnutls-compat
make
./lynx https://mail.google.com
```

Remember to use `--prefix=`*`<prefix of directory containing lynx.cfg>`* and `--with-pkg-config=`*`<directory prefix of binaries>`* with configure. I use Arch Linux so these were "/" and "/usr" respectively, For debian based distros you shouldn't need these. I just thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: still doesnt work. I am using 2.8.8

Comment: What distro, OS and release (if not rolling release) are you using?

Comment: Nice answer, @andreasw. +1 for you.

Comment: Mac OS X. I will try to implement this and get back.

Comment: You may just want to build & install with Fink or MacPorts. The lynx packages from both systems include support for https. Also, that way you have it managed by a package manager.

Answer (score 2):

I used MacPorts to install lynx

```
port info lynx  
lynx @2.8.7rel.1, Revision 1 (www)  
Variants: gnutls, [+]ssl, universal
```

to install:

```
sudo port install lynx +ssl
```

Lynx will access my gmail!
I changed the following option so not to be asked each time:

#### SSL Prompting

This allows you to tell how to handle errors detected in SSL connections prompt normally to prompt for each cookie, force yes-response to reply "yes" to each prompt, force no-response to reply "no" to each prompt.